# How to scan a table and retrieve the lowest value

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb

I want to retrieve a minimum value from a table in dynamodb (in Javascript). the value that I want to get is of a regular attribute, and not a **key**. If there is more than one- then I would like to limit it to just one.

for example, I have a table of events. the key is the user Id and the sort key is the event Id. I want to get the event with the minimum number of attendees, which is an extra attribute.

Can anyone help me please?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is a table of values, a simple for loop check should do the trick:

```
    for(i = 0; i < rowLength; i ++)
    {
            for(j = 0; j < columnLength; j ++)
            {
                    temp = table.numberOfAttendees[i][j];
                    if(temp < minimum)
                    {
                            minimum = temp;
                            rowOfMin = i;
                            columnOfMin = j;
                    }
            }
    }
```

Before execution:

- declare i, j, minimum, temp, rowOfMin, and columnOfMin(I don't know the syntax)
- make sure that minimum is set to some high value so that no values will be overlooked

After execution:

- minimum will be the smallest number of attendees
- rowOfMin and columnOfMin will be the indexes of the table

Hope this helps!